# Как кастомизировать QScrollBar определенным образом?

Tags: python, pyqt, qss, qscrollarea, qscrollbar

Главный контейнер моего приложения `box` содержит **`15`** простых кнопок `QPushButton` и имеет *вертикальную* полосу прокрутки, визуальные характеристики которой мне нужно изменить.

Я видел таблицы стиля для `QScrollBar`, но так и не понял как устроены устроены эти объемные конструкции.

Попытки переделать их под свои нужды всегда приводили к ошибке:

> Could not parse stylesheet of object QScrollArea

---

Мне нужно, чтобы полоса удовлетворяла следующим параметрам:

1. Ширина полосы (на рисунке обозначена цифрой **`2`**) должна быть **`10px`**. Углы полосы должны быть **`скруглены`**.
2. Ширина заднего фона полосы (на рисунке обозначена цифрой **`1`**) должна быть **`10px`**. Углы заднего фона полосы должны быть **`скруглены`**.
3. Стрелки вверх/вниз на концах полосы (на рисунке обозначены цифрой **`3`**) должны не иметь фона, рамок и прочих лишних элементов. Мне нужно, чтобы они представляли из себя простые круги диаметром **`10px`**.

Вот png-картинка такого круга:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пожалуйста, скажите, как это сделать?

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea()
        content_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        scrollArea.setWidget(content_widget)
        scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        scrollArea.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        scrollArea.setStyleSheet(stylesheet)
        box1 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(content_widget)

        for n in range(1, 15):
            btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(f'Button{n}',
                                        clicked = lambda ch, n=n: print(f'Button{n}'))
            box1.addWidget(btn, n-1, 0)

        box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        box.addWidget(scrollArea)

stylesheet = (''' border-style: hidden; ''') # Важно сохранить эту характеристику


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если это то, что вам надо, то цвета отрегулируете самостоятельно. Если что-то не так, напишите - что не так.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea()
        scrollArea.setObjectName("scrollArea")                        # +
        content_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        scrollArea.setStyleSheet("border-style: hidden;")             # Важно сохранить эту характеристику
        scrollArea.setWidget(content_widget)
        scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        scrollArea.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        
        box1 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(content_widget)
        for n in range(1, 15):
            btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(f'Button{n}',
                                        clicked = lambda ch, n=n: print(f'Button{n}'))
            box1.addWidget(btn, n-1, 0)

        box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        box.addWidget(scrollArea)


Stylesheet = ("""
#scrollArea QScrollBar:vertical {
    background-color: #2A29ff;                  
    width: 10px;          
    margin: 15px 0px 15px 0px;                   
    border: 0px transparent #2A29ff;             
    border-radius: 5px;                          
}
#scrollArea QScrollBar::handle:vertical {
    background-color: red;         
    min-height: 10px;                            
    border-radius: 5px;                          
}
#scrollArea QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical {
    margin: 3px 0px 3px 0px;
    border-image: url(circle.png);                 /* (./images/up_arrow_disabled.png)  */      
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    subcontrol-position: top;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
#scrollArea QScrollBar::add-line:vertical {
    margin: 3px 0px 3px 0px;
    border-image: url(circle.png);                 /* (./images/down_arrow_disabled.png) */          
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    subcontrol-position: bottom;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
#scrollArea QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical:hover,QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical:on {
    border-image: url(circle.png);                 /* (./images/up_arrow.png) */                   
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    subcontrol-position: top;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
#scrollArea QScrollBar::add-line:vertical:hover, QScrollBar::add-line:vertical:on {
    border-image: url(circle.png);                 /* (./images/down_arrow.png) */                  
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    subcontrol-position: bottom;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
#scrollArea QScrollBar::up-arrow:vertical, QScrollBar::down-arrow:vertical {
    background: none;
}
#scrollArea QScrollBar::add-page:vertical, QScrollBar::sub-page:vertical {
    background: none;
}
""")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    app.setStyleSheet(Stylesheet)                                 # +++
    
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Все так, как мне было нужно. Спасибо!